# drop down inside check box bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I'm using bootstrap 2 and i want a drop down inside check box label like this.

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    i want to buy
    <select class="which">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    something
</label>
```

i want clicking on 'something' change status of checkbox. it's cool in chrome, but in firefox the drop down doesn't work and clicking on it changes status of checkbox. i use'd stop propagation method but doesn't help. this way of using drop down and checkbox is true? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is illegal markup. Try [validate](http://validator.w3.org/check) the the above code. It will report "*The label element may contain at most one input, button, select, textarea, or keygen descendant*."

You have two inputs. Seems FireFox renders this "correct", the select box as part of the label, triggering its parent, the label, when it is clicked.

I suggest you make valid markup, using two labels :

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    i want to buy
</label>
<select class="which">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>
<label for="check">
    something
</label>
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/AbaZH/** works in FireFox (also)

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="buyCheckbox">
<label class="checkbox" for="buyCheckbox">
     i want to buy
</label>
<select class="which">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<label class="checkbox" for="buyCheckbox">
     something
</label>
```